# left/right click with different mouseMoveEvents

Tags: qt

So I am using `mousePressEvent` with `mouseMoveEvent`, however I want to use right click event and mousemoveevent to work differently. How can I make `mouseMoveEvent` to work differently for left click and right click? The below code causes my program to crash, whenever I run it and click it closes

Also I'd like to add have this range field [image] which would allow me to change value from 1 to 100, how can I add this, and how can I bind integer value to it?

```
bool left;
bool right;
void MyWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{

    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
       left = true;

    }
   if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
       right = true;

    }
    

}

void MyWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
 if(left).. logic
 if(right).. logic
}
```

Comment: Is this one question or two questions? The text of the question does not make any sense to me. Please try to explain it better what you want to achieve.

Comment: @V.K. two questions

Comment: maybe just keep in one member variable which button was pressed and then use this variable in the move event

Comment: @t0xicf please provide a [mre]

Comment: why don't you use `event->button() == Qt::LeftButton` etc. also in `mouseMoveEvent`? there is no need for `left` and `right` variables.